# CodeIgniter - make URL shorter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I'm new to CodeIgniter.
 I make one site and i want my url to be shorter.
 For example, now the url is

```
http://example.com/planner/planner/index.php/planner/main
```

and i want to be

```
 http://example.com/planner/planner/main.
```

Firstly, i remove the index.php tag, but after that url gives me an 404 error.
 I want to remove index.php and the controller name.
Anybody knows how can i do that?

PS. My URL works only with index.php tag ...

Comment: This question has at least 5 duplicates. http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/155801/

Comment: what are Planner/planner in the url...........??

Comment: that would be a controller folder called "planner" and then a controller called "planner". Controller -> Planner -> Planner.php

Comment: In that case, you are going it all wrong way.

Comment: The first two /planner/planner are the folders from my root directory. After index.php i had my controller name ( "planner" ) and my view ("main")

Answer (score 1):

make .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

edit MYAPPLICATION_FOLDER\config\config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

READ USERGUIDE

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: I make it, but that's only remove my index.php tag and after that my url doesn't work. I don't know why my url works only with index.php tag

Answer (score 1):

You can remove index.php from your url using below code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But for further shortening of your url you need to sue route remap functionality by codeIgniter. You can find about it in [codeigntier User guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) clearly under URL routing.

Routing rules are defined in your application/config/routes.php file. In it you'll see an array called $route that permits you to specify your own routing criteria. Routes can either be specified using wildcards or Regular Expressions

```
 Wildcards
```

A typical wildcard route might look something like this:

```
 $route['product/:num'] = "catalog/product_lookup";
```

In a route, the array key contains the URI to be matched, while the array value contains the destination it should be re-routed to. In the above example, if the literal word "product" is found in the first segment of the URL, and a number is found in the second segment, the "catalog" class and the "product_lookup" method are instead used.

You can match literal values or you can use two wildcard types:

(:num) will match a segment containing only numbers.
(:any) will match a segment containing any character.

Note: Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.
Examples

Here are a few routing examples:

```
   $route['journals'] = "blogs";
```

A URL containing the word "journals" in the first segment will be remapped to the "blogs" class.

```
   $route['blog/joe'] = "blogs/users/34";
```

A URL containing the segments blog/joe will be remapped to the "blogs" class and the "users" method. The ID will be set to "34".

```
   $route['product/(:any)'] = "catalog/product_lookup";
```

A URL with "product" as the first segment, and anything in the second will be remapped to the "catalog" class and the "product_lookup" method.

```
   $route['product/(:num)'] = "catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1";
```

A URL with "product" as the first segment, and a number in the second will be remapped to the "catalog" class and the "product_lookup_by_id" method passing in the match as a variable to the function.

Comment: I make it, but that's only remove my index.php tag and after that my url doesn't work. I don't know why my url works only with index.php tag

Comment: yes, i remove index.php but after that i can't go further with my site... For example: http://example.com/planner/planner/index.php/planner/admin works well. After that i remove index.php . The link will be http://example.com/planner/planner/planner/admin and the link won't work ...

Comment: yes , i did. Now i remain only with http://example.com/planner/planner/admin but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give me exactly what have i need to add to $route .... I can mention that planner is my default controller and admin is one view

Comment: read user guide properly and first try to implement basic MVC then do your application.........

Comment: yes but if i add index.php to my url it works. http://example.com/planner/planner/index.php/planner/admin works , and http://example.com/planner/planner/admin doesn't work

Comment: Can it be from my apache server ?